# Cannot retrieve chunks of data from BlockingCollection<T>

Tags: c#, producer-consumer, blockingcollection

I often find myself in a situation where I do want to stream data in chunks rather then one by one. Usually I do this when I need to do some I/O based operation like database inserts where I want to limit roundtrips.
So I got myself this nice little extension method:

```
        public static IEnumerable<List<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, int size)
        {            
            using (var enumerator = data.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return YieldBatchElements(enumerator, size - 1).ToList();
                }
            }

            IEnumerable<TU> YieldBatchElements<TU>(
                IEnumerator<TU> source,
                int batchSize)
            {
                yield return source.Current;
                for (var i = 0; i < batchSize && source.MoveNext(); i++)
                {
                    yield return source.Current;
                }
            }
        }
```

This works just fine but I noticed that it does not work with `BlockCollection<T> GetConsumingEnumerable`

I created following Test Method to demonstrate my findings:

```
        [Test]
        public static void ConsumeTest()
        {
            var queue = new BlockingCollection<int>();
            var i = 0;
            foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Split(3))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Fetched chunk: {x.Count}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Fetched total: {i += x.Count}");
            }
            //Fetched chunk: 3
            //Fetched total: 3
            //Fetched chunk: 3
            //Fetched total: 6
            //Fetched chunk: 3
            //Fetched total: 9
            //Fetched chunk: 1
            //Fetched total: 10
         

            Task.Run(
                () =>
                    {
                        foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
                        {
                            queue.Add(x);
                        }
                    });

            i = 0;
            foreach (var element in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(
                new CancellationTokenSource(3000).Token).Split(3))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Fetched chunk: {element.Count}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Fetched total: {i += element.Count}");
            }

            //Fetched chunk: 3
            //Fetched total: 3
            //Fetched chunk: 3
            //Fetched total: 6
            //Fetched chunk: 3
            //Fetched total: 9
        }
```

Apparently the last chunk is being "dropped" if there are less elements than chunk size.
Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Describe the actual problem, not the attempt to solve it. `BlockingCollection` is *not* meant for stream processing. There are purpose-built libraries and classes for this, eg the TPL Dataflow or Channels. A `BatchBlock` will batch incoming messages into batches of N items with a single line of code. `ActionBlock` and `TransformBlock` will process incoming messages using 1 or more worker tasks `LinkTo` will pass messages from one block to another without extra code. Almost all Dataflow block types have built-in input and if applicable, output buffers

Comment: Thx I will have a look at those. Still I am curious what is actually causing the issue. GetConsumingEnumerable exposes an IEnumerable that I should be able to iterate as it pleases me.

Comment: Does the problem persists if instead of the `Split` you use the [`Chunk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk) LINQ operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should call **CompleteAdding()** method to inform the **GetConsumingEnumerable()** that there are no more elements to add from its producer(s).

The below code change will fix your issue and prints the missing lines.

```
Task.Run(() =>
              {
                 foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
                 {
                    queue.Add(x);
                 }
                    queue.CompleteAdding(); // After executing the line, IsCompleted property of queue will be true.
              });
```

Please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable?view=net-7.0) link for more info about GetConsumingEnumerable() of the BlockingCollection.

Comment: Just to add more info on the behavior. The Cancellation will happen after 3 seconds and it will ABORT the operation (meaning discards the remaining elements instead of returning them (one element in our case)).